# What parameters to use in this function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to put this piece of code into a function so that i can avoid just copy pasting the code everytime. Here the code that I want to put in a function:

```
f= open("test.txt","w+")
os.chdir("//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes")
for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
    duration = today - modified_date
    if duration.days < 1:
        f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")
```

edit1: I have changed my code like Chepner's advice now the issue still remains that there is no output being written to my test.txt file.
What am I missing ?

Thanks alot!

Comment: if you simply want to call it, you can use ```def function1():``` directly. you don't need any parameters.

Comment: I want it to do the code inside of it, so when i put `def function1():` and later call it, it doesn't do anything :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, you don't need any parameters (though I'm going to re-write it slightly to use a `with` statement):

```
def my_function():
    with open("test.txt", "w+") as f:
        os.chdir("//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes")
        for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
            duration = today - modified_date
            if duration.days < 1:
                f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")

my_function()
```

You might want to parameterize the function in several ways, however. Both the hard-coded output file name and the input directory are candidates.

```
def my_function(output_name, input_dir):
    with open(output_name, "w+") as f:
        os.chdir(input_dir)
        for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
            duration = today - modified_date
            if duration.days < 1:
                f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")

my_function("test.txt", "//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, the problem is that it doesn't write anything to my test.txt. What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right directory? It should be in the directory from which you *ran* the script, not the input directory, since you called `chdir` *after* you opened the file for writing.

Comment: Also, verify that `duration.days < 1` is ever true.

Comment: OK you are my hero, it was just the test.txt file that wasn't being updated each time I ran the code again !!

Comment: Ok I am in need of your help again. How would i go about calling the function multiple times like so: `my_function("output1.txt", "//10.2.30.61/c$\test/test\test")
    my_function("output2.txt", "//10.2.30.61/c$\test1/test1\test1")
    my_function("output3.txt", "//10.2.30.61/c$\test1/test1\test1")` So that each time it produces a different output.txt and the input_dir changes. I have tried manually changing it but it seems to only take the first call and not process the second one. Thanks!!

Comment: Please open a new question. Comments are not for extending the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one answer to this question. It depends on how you want to reuse this function. You can start by asking yourself these questions:

1. Will I always have to open the same file i.e. `test.txt` or if it not, you can set it as an argument.
2. Will I always change directory to the same folder i.e. `"//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes"`
3. Will I always write the same text to files i.e `{fichiers} = {duration} \n`

If these things change in different context, you can make them arguments. But, if everything will be the same, you can just define a function without **any** arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a function `without` any parameter you can do like:

```
def my_function():
  f= open("test.txt","w+")
  os.chdir("//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes")
  for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
     today = datetime.datetime.today()
      modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
      duration = today - modified_date
      if duration.days < 1:
        f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")
```

Call it simply like: `my_function()`

Function `with parameters`: Based on the code you have provided, you can keep file name and url as parameters to the function like:

Functions with parameters can be used again and again with different parameters

```
def my_function(fileName, URL):
  f= open(fileName,"w+")
  os.chdir(URL)
  for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
    duration = today - modified_date
    if duration.days < 1:
        f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")
```

Then call it like:

```
my_function("test.txt", "//10.2.30.61/c$\Qlikview_Tropal/apps/ventes")
```